# Null Hypothesis at 5% level of significance

Tags: probability, statistics

When a null hypothesis is accepted at 5% level of significance, what is the probability that the decision made is wrong?

Comment: Welcome. You will be most likely to get good answers if you provide context for your question and tell us what thoughts you have about it.

Comment: Fisher would say that you never *accept* the null hypothesis, you merely do not reject it.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of accepting the null hypothesis when it wrong depends on the alternatives. That is without specifying the alternatives you do not know the false positive rate of a hypothesis test, you only know that the probability of rejecting the null-hypothesis when it is in fact true is 5%.

Answer (score 0):

In frequentist (that is, non-Bayesian) hypothesis testing, probabilities are not assigned to $H_0$ and $H_1$. So, sorry, it is NOT permitted to ask for the probability that the null hypothesis is wrong. You CAN talk about the probability of accepting or rejecting a hypothesis under various assumptions about shapes of distributions and values (not probabilities!!) of parameters.

If you toss a coin 25 times without getting a Head, it would be rational to "reject" the null hypothesis that it is fair. You could quote a P-value (which IS a probability) to say how unlikely such an extreme event is, given that the null hypothesis is true. But if the P-value is .01, it is total nonsense to say things like "the probability the null hypothesis is true is .01."